# Sort attribute table and perform sequential calculation using Field Calculator

Tags: qgis

I have an attribute table with a Time attribute (UTCtime) which I want to use to create markers which I will later use to split the features. Example of table below. I will do this by taking the difference between UTCtime at row 2 and subtracting the UTCtime from row 1. When I have a value >1 I want it to put a character like $ in a column so I can split the features at this point and/or group them.

How can I create the Diff column in QGIS and avoid getting the inevitable weird value at the end of the table (-1305510005.40)?

```
UTCtime   Group  Diff   
1305509644  1   0.10
1305509644  1   0.00
1305509644  1   0.10
1305509644  1   0.00
1305509644  1   0.10
1305509645  1   0.00
1305509645  1   0.10
1305509645  1   0.00
1305509645  1   360.40
1305510005  2   0.00
1305510005  2   0.10
1305510005  2   0.00
1305510005  2   0.10
1305510005  2   0.00
1305510005  2   0.10
1305510005  2   0.00
1305510005  2   0.10
1305510005  2   -1305510005.40
```

Comment: What is the *row 2*, is it a `"Group"` field?

Comment: It's just row 2 from UTCTime, so for example if this was in excel what I'm trying to do A2-A1. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: What is your time format? What does "1305509644" mean? Does not seem to make any sense for me.... What is Year, month, day, hour, minute, sec etc.?

Comment: You have just three different values for `UTCtime` in your example. How can it be that there is a difference (your third field) between most of them? Sorry, your data don't make sense, please explain.

Comment: It doesn't matter what UTCTime actually is for this example, just treat it like a simple number that increments forward in either 0 or 0.1 increments. I just want to be able to make a column named Diff that calculates the difference between each UTCTime measurement, and then if the value is >1 I want to give it a specific value, like $ or similar.

Comment: OK, abstracting from your data, I posted a solution that shows the principle. I hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula to substract `UCTime`-value of the next entry from the `UCTime`-value of the current entry is:

```
attribute (
    get_feature_by_id(
        @layer, 
        $id+1)
    , 'UCTime')-
"UCTime"
```

The last entry is a `NULL` (no data) value as there is no next entry to substract from.

*See screenshot for results:*
[image]

---

Your additional question in the comment about sorting: you can create a new field `sort` that creates a number that orders your values: 1 for the smallest, 2 for the next higher etc.:

```
array_find( 
    array_distinct(
        array_sort ( 
            array_agg( 
                UCTime
            ),
            true
        )
    ),
    UCTime
)+1
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for your help. Is there any way to sort the attribute table by 'UTCTime' first before running this?

Comment: I added that. However, your data contain repeating values: how you want to sort these? What exactly you want to achieve based on what? When asking a question, it helps a lot to make your use case clear and provide a real scenario with realistic values - can be dummy data, but data structure etc. should become clear and be comparable to what you finally want to do. Otherwise, each answer risks to provoke a new problem. In your case, you will get just three values (1, 2 and 3) for sort order as you have duplicate values.